# Open a Single Dropdown Menu (Instead of all of them)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I followed the documentation to create a dropdown menu using Material UI. However, none of the docs have a good example for handling multiple dropdowns in the same menu.

I got it mostly working - however, when I open a dropdown, they ALL open. I'm assuming this is because `open = Boolean(anchorEl)` opens the menu whenever an `anchorEl` is set. So how can I adjust this so it only opens the specific menu that is clicked?

```
const NavBarMainMenu = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl)
  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
  }
  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "none", lg: "flex" } }}>
        {pages.map(page => {
          return (
            <>
              <Button
                key={page.title}
                id={page.title + "-button"}
                onClick={handleClick}
                aria-controls={open ? page.title : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={open ? "true" : undefined}
              >
                {page.title}
              </Button>
              <Menu
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                id={page.title}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                onClick={handleClose}
                transformOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "top" }}
                anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "bottom" }}
              >
                {page.children.map(child => {
                  return <MenuItem key={child.title}>{child.title}</MenuItem>
                })}
              </Menu>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
const NavBarMainMenu = () => {
  const [anchorEls, setAnchorEls] = useState({}) // <-- Here use a object
  const isOpen = (id) => Boolean(anchorEls[id]) // <-- Here you need a function to get if open is true

  const handleClick = (event, id) => {
    setAnchorEsl({ ...anchorEls, [id]: event.currentTarget }) // <-- Here you set anchor value using an id
  }
  const handleClose = (id) => {
    setAnchorEls({ ...anchorEls, [id]: null }) // <-- Here you delete anchor value by ID
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, display: { xs: "none", lg: "flex" } }}>
        {pages.map(page => {
          return (
            <>
              <Button
                key={page.title}
                id={page.title + "-button"}
                onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, page.title)}
                aria-controls={isOpen(page.title) ? page.title : undefined}
                aria-haspopup="true"
                aria-expanded={isOpen(page.title) ? "true" : undefined}
              >
                {page.title}
              </Button>
              <Menu
                anchorEl={anchorEls[page.title]}
                id={page.title}
                open={isOpen(page.title)}
                onClose={() => handleClose(page.title)}
                onClick={() => handleClose(page.title)}
                transformOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "top" }}
                anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "right", vertical: "bottom" }}
              >
                {page.children.map(child => {
                  return <MenuItem key={child.title}>{child.title}</MenuItem>
                })}
              </Menu>
            </>
          )
        })}
      </Box>
    </>
  )
}
```